# MPI calculate difference sign from double array

Tags: c++, arrays, mpi

I'm trying to calculate difference sign from double array with MPI, no need to use outside rows or cols, the result may look like that:

In array

> 1 0 1 1 1
>
> 2 1 3 1 4
>
> 1 3 1 0 1
>
> 2 1 -1 1 2

out array

> 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 -1 0 -1 0
>
> 0 1 -1 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 0 0

I wrote some code but when I'm trying to write b array to the console I'm getting Access Violation Reading Location error. I'm new in MPI and I don't know if this code is correct. Any ideas how to get it work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int size, rank;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

srand(time(NULL));

int R = 4;
int C = 8;


int **a = new int *[R];
a = new int *[R]; 
a[0] = new int[R*C];
for (int i = 1; i < R; i++)
{
    a[i] = &a[0][i*C];
}

if (rank == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) 
        {
            a[i][j] = (rand() % 10) - 5;
            cout << setw(5) << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}


int **b = new int *[R];
b = new int *[R]; 
b[0] = new int[R*C];
for (int i = 1; i < R; i++)
{
    b[i] = &b[0][i*C];
}


MPI_Bcast(a, R*C, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

int partR = R / size;
int partC = C / size;
int part = partR * partC*size; 

int *c = new int[part];

int sumF = 0;
int sumS = 0;
int tmp = 0;
int x = 0;

auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

for (int i = rank*partR; i <= rank*partR+partR; i++) {
    for (int j = rank*partC; j <= rank*partC + partC; j++) {
        if (i != 0 && i != R - 1 && j != 0 && j != C - 1) {
            sumF = a[i - 1][j - 1] + a[i + 1][j - 1] + a[i - 1][j + 1] + a[i + 1][j + 1];
            sumS = a[i - 1][j] + a[i + 1][j] + a[i][j - 1] + a[i][j + 1];
            if ((sumF - sumS) > 0)
                tmp = 1;
            if ((sumF - sumS) < 0)
                tmp = -1;
            if ((sumF - sumS) == 0)
                tmp = 0;
            c[x] = tmp;
            x++;
        }
    }
}

MPI_Gather(c, part, MPI_INT, &(b[0][0]), part, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


auto finish = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;

if (rank == 0) {
    cout << endl << "Result: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            cout << b[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "T: " << elapsed.count() << endl;
}


MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You are sending an array of pointers to another process. Pointers point to process' address space, thus they cannot be valid in another process address space.

Answer (score 0):

```
MPI_Bcast(a, R*C, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

That's not broadcasting a 2D array. This takes the `int**`, transforms it into a `void*` and you tell the compiler that it contains `R*C` integers. it doesn't. It contained addresses to subarrays.

Use a 1D array instead in a future refactoring. 1D accesses without indirections are better.

But to fix your issue for now:

```
MPI_Bcast(a[0], R*C, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right but should it be a[0] or a[0][0] as it's the first element. Anyway the same exception still occurs even if I fix it.

Comment: It can be `a[0]` or `&a[0][0]`. sendcount for gather should be `part / size`

Comment: @folk is it during the MPI call or somewhere else?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Why divided by `size`?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I think it should be just part not part/size as I get entire c array from each thread to b array. I fixed my Gather function  with recv pointer and initialized c array correctly. But still getting Access Violation when I run it on 4 threads and I'm not sure where it is as I can't debug on 4 threads but it's somewhere in the big dobule /for/ block. Have no ideas for now. Will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Unless I read it wrong, you only set `c[0:partR*partC-1]`. Should a task work on a full rows instead of a sub-square ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet indeed, there is a mismatch between the allocation and the computed size.

Comment: `if (i != 0 && i != R - 1 && j != 0 && j != C - 1)` is incorrect, try `if ((i != 0) && (i != (R - 1)) && (j != 0) && (j != (C - 1)))` instead. you will get incorrect result (see my previous comment) but no crash.